# Are there any Mining OS to be started from USB?

Tags: mining-setup, miner-configuration

Considering my PC as a mining rig I don't want to install anything on HD. Setting up a system with full GUI mining capabilites (proprietary drivers, OpenCL, ...) can take some time. An out of the box solution would be nice.

Are there any preconfigured OS distributions (maybe Linux) containing all you need to boot and mine without further configurations?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[LinuxCoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/LinuxCoin) is probably the closest thing to what you're looking for. According to the wiki, Linuxcoin is:

> A lightweight Debian-based OS which includes in the image everything
>   that is necessary to run as a Bitcoin client and everything needed to
>   get started mining on ATI hardware.

***Edit:** It may also be worth looking into [BAMT](http://aaronwolfe.com/bamt/) if your operation is of significant size*

***Update:** How things change... BAMT is now the de facto mining distro. I'm now having a difficult time even finding a live link to download LinuxCoin from and BAMT has gone from experimental to a full-fledged mining distro usable for nearly any scale. I highly recommend BAMT over LinuxCoin.*

Comment: it should also be noted that LinuxCoin is rather heavyweight, it does not like running on small dedicated systems.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of rolling my own when LinuxCoin was proving too difficult to set up, and I have never heard of BAMT. I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but still showing up in Google, so it is time for an update for 2019.

https://getpimp.org/

https://simplemining.net/

https://www.smos-linux.org/

http://ethosdistro.com/

https://hiveos.farm/